# Is it safe to use break inside list_for_each_entry?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is it safe to use a break instruction for a `while/for` loop, which is inside a `list_for_each_entry` instruction (in the Linux kernel)?

By example:

```
list_for_each_entry(obj1, vars, list) {
    ...
    while(j < k)
    {
        ...
        if(k >= MAX_ITERATIONS) break; // break the while
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Will the while loop be broken as expected or will the `list_for_each_entry` be broken?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`break` *always* breaks out of only the innermost loop, so the outer loop is not affected.  In fact, to break out of multiple levels of loops, you have to use `goto`.